# How can I abdicate my throne to my heir?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

I am getting a bit bored by my current character, and my heir is a much better one. So I would like to end my characters reign rather sooner than later and continue playing as my heir instead. Do I have to find some way to kill myself? Perhaps even via the "Commit Suicide" decision despite its hefty penalty for my dynasty? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way I found to abdicate and pass on the throne to my heir is by intentionally getting deposed.

1. Make sure your Crown authority / Tribal authority is high enough that you can revoke titles.
2. Try to revoke titles from your strongest and most rebellious De-Jure vassals until one says no and starts a "War against the Tyranny"
3. Surrender immediately

The punishment for losing a "War against your Tyranny" against a vassal who is DeJure part of your primary title is getting deposed. Getting deposed is functionally identical to dying: All your titles get transferred to your current heirs depending on their respective succession laws, and your primary heir becomes your new player-character.

The only difference is that your previous character is still alive and will usually hang around as a courtier in your court.

Comment: Bonus - if your heir gets deposed, your old king might be reinstated!

Answer (score 2):

To add to this answer, there is an "attempt suicide" that will present itself under certain circumstances:

```
One of the following:
Cancer trait
Depressed trait
Great Pox trait
Incapable trait
Leper trait
Lunatic trait
Stress Level 3
Best Friend, Soulmate or Child with high Opinion died
```

Going on hunts also presents a small chance of dying.

Overall this aspect of the game is designed towards roleplaying and generally characters don't want to die.

Comment: I wouldn't be opposed to a future mechanic allowing a ruler to "co-rule" with their heir, which is something that has taken place somewhat often throughout history. It would be fun to play as the heir while the predecessor takes the place of your spouse as the assistant. Perhaps my character wouldn't earn prestige for the titles held, but could instead spend his predecessor's prestige.